# WordPress code problem

Tags: errors, code

I have this code shown in the picture on top of the search bar. It appears on all pages.

[image]

I have checked all the plug-ins and it is still there. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: search for `sg_popup` in the files of the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shortcode of the [Popup builder plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-builder/) that for some reason is not being evaluated. Is that plugin installed?

Most likely the shortcode is in a widget somewhere. It could also be in a theme file.

Comment: What file in the file folder should I look at?

Comment: I found the code in the header file. the code is:

<?php
    do_action( 'setwood_before_content' ); ?>

    <div id="content" class="site-content" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="col-full">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sg_popup id=14]'); ?>
        <?php
        do_action( 'setwood_content_top' ); ?>

What should I do?

Comment: Is that plugin installed? If not, install it and everything should be fine. Or if you don't want it, remove the `<?php echo do_shortcode('[sg_popup id=14]'); ?>` part.

Answer (score 1):

this is shortcode this coming from the sidebar, go to appearance -> widget. select the sidebar and remove shortcode.

Comment: I just checked all my widgets and it is nothing t d with them as the code is still there,